# adding npm packages to windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, npm, command-prompt

I have installed node and npm onto my computer without a problem (I am running windows 8) however this is my first time using windows and I cant seem to access any packages I install without getting an error message `Could not find files for the given` I should also mention im working in visual studios on a .net and angular project, the node is just for testing.

```
where node gives me C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe 

where npm gives me C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
```

but I know the karma package I installed went to `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` I have added a NODE_PATH to my environment variables but it didnt help. Any thoughts?

this is a snippet from command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules>dir
 Volume in drive C is 000000
 Volume Serial Number is 000000

 Directory of C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

2015-01-05  06:39 PM    <DIR>          .
2015-01-05  06:39 PM    <DIR>          ..
2015-01-05  06:39 PM    <DIR>          karma
2015-01-05  06:39 PM    <DIR>          karma-cli
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  918,342,209,536 bytes free


C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules>where karma
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use the command-line command `karma` or `require()` the package in a module?  You need to install packages differently for these use cases.

```
> npm install -g karma
```

Will install the `karma` package globally, and it should then be accessible from your command line.  You may need to close and re-open your command prompt or re-set the PATH environment var.

If you want to use the package with `require`, you will need to create a package directory, run `npm init`, and then install `karma` locally with `npm install --save karma`.  This will install the package under the `node_modules` directory **for that package only**.  `npm` does this to avoid conflicts between different packages which may require different versions of the same package.

Please forgive me if I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Thanks Sam you are right. I didnt realize I needed/could add a package.json file to a visual studios project (silly me) and for some reason installing karma globally made it still unavailable globally. however I seem to be able to run npm install --save karma to my project but I noticed the files added (node_modles, package.json) are not available from within visual studios. Is this normal? My project file now contains node_modules, packages, npm-debug, package and the visual studios testApp file (the testApp file being the actual project). DOS prompt wont let me get any deeper into testApp

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, so I can't comment on that.  When `npm` installs a package locally, it puts the binaries (or on Windows, little shim files that execute the binaries) inside .\node_modules\.bin so you should be able to run karma from the command line like this:

`.\node_modules\bin\karma` 

You can also define scripts in `package.json`; the advantage to doing this is that these scripts are run with `.\node_modules\.bin` in their path, so if package.json has

scripts: { "test": "karma" }

then `npm run test` will run karma for you.

Comment: (BTW `npm test` is a shorthand for `npm run test` but if you define your own scripts, you will need the full `npm run <scriptname>` syntax.)

Good luck with the Visual Studio part, I'm sorry I can't be of more help.  Microsoft has some tools for `node` development under Windows here - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/  - but as I say, I haven't used them.

Comment: hey @Sam Mikes I figured out how to run commands from VS but it is looking for npm under Users\Regan when I have it installed (by defulat under Users\Admin I changed the Path in environmental variable to show this but its not doing anything. do you know how to move this? the error message is :  npm : Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\Regan\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: If you install `node` as yourself (instead of as administrator) then it will install to your own C:\Users\<username>\AppData ; but in this case I think it would be better to change the NODE_PATH variable to point to C:\Users\Admin... because I think that is what's causing `node` and `npm` to look in the wrong place; or possibly the `prefix` config setting of node.

If you come over to <https://github.com/npm/npm> and file an issue there, someone who knows more about Windows can help..